# How to append Git commit information the built website

Tags: git

I use an automated script to get the latest (or a specific) git commit, build and deploy my platform.
I want to append the commit details upon each build, so it will be possible to see which commit was used to build the platform.

What is a good strategy to achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Eduardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command can get current commit digest.

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

output:

```
3ba7598
```

You can save this digest upon each build.

Answer (score 0):

You can shell out to `git` to get the commit info:

```
<footer>
  BUILD:
  <?php echo(system('git log -1 --format=%h')) ?>
</footer>
```